# Shouldn't the space complexity of insertion sort be O(N)?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort

This covers a "software algorithm" from https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

This is a from a lecture slide from class 
[image]

Here is the implementation of insertion sort that we used

```
public static void insertionSort(int[] a) {
     for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
          int temp = a[i];
          int j = i;
          while (j >= 1 && a[j - 1] > temp) {
                a[j] = a[j - 1];
         }
         a[j] = temp;
     }
}
```

I would agree that the space complexity of local variables would be O(1) because its just the same local variables each time no matter the input size, i, j, and temp will each take up a block of memory.

However I am confused about the space complexity of the array. http://www.cs.northwestern.edu/academics/courses/311/html/space-complexity.html had a similar example,

```
int sum(int a[], int n) {
    int r = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
       r += a[i];
    }
    return r;
}
```

and said that this algorithm would require N units of memory for a, meaning its space complexity is O(N)?

Which is it? O(N) because the array would require N units of memory(dependent on input size) or O(1) because of pass by reference?

Comment: It's a question of whether a read/write array argument should count, which apparently is a matter of opinion (I would have thought that the consensus is that it doesn't).

Comment: Since you are sorting in place you are not using _additional_ memory for the array, i.e., the algorithm space complexity is O(1). It's common to ignore the size of the input when measuring the space complexity because the input is there regardless of the algorithm.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat What do you mean by read/write array?

Comment: Ugh.  It pays to be pedantic about this sort of stuff as you present it.  You might point this out to your lecturer.

Comment: It's totally O(n^2); the nested loop alone suggests that. However, best case scenario is, in fact, O(n) as the inner loop isn't executed.

Comment: Whoops, I didn't completely read your question, sorry.

Comment: @amaleemur, OP is discussing space complexity, not time complexity, something you seem to have worked out one second before I posted this comment :-)

Comment: Hehe, no problem; I guess I just had a read after write error (har har). I'm pretty sure most if not all in place sorting algorithms have a space complexity of O(1) though.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [cs.stackexchange.com](http://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Eliran, you may want to go investigate the _other_ 6000-odd questions on `{big-o, complexity-theory, time-complexity, space-complexity}` to see if they need closing as well :-) While it may be a CS topic, that doesn't _necessarily_ mean it doesn't belong here as well. Complexity analysis of algorithms _is_ of concern to programmers, at least those that want to write efficient code.

Comment: @paxdiablo, i see your point, but in this particular case, the question may pose an issue as answers are primarily opinion-based. IMHO this is a result of the context - on the CS site there's more room for such (theoretical) questions, so i chose to vote close as belongs on another site and not as primarily opinion based. thanks for the input.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Array passed by reference` means that you're sorting in-place, with no *extra* space need for the output data.

Hence the space complexity (what you need over and above the original data set <sup>(a)</sup>) is a constant `O(1)` rather than a linear `O(n)`.

In terms of the final code snippet, that *too* is `O(1)` simply because arrays degrade to first-element-pointers when passed to a function. The author seems to understand the concept with their comment at the bottom of the linked page:

> But be careful here. If things are passed by pointer or reference, then space is shared. If A passes a C-style array to B, there is no new space allocated.

But, for some reason, they seem to believe that passing the array will make a copy <sup>(b)</sup>.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> If space complexity were to include the original data set, then `O(1)` complexity would be *impossible.*

---

<sup>(b)</sup> And, since the best person able to speak on behalf of the author is the author himself, I reached out with a question, and the response explains the distinction between the two cases. I *hope* he doesn't mind since, as an educator, I would presume he has the same "increase-overall-knowledge-in-the-world" attitude as I, and it shows a level of respect for that attitude that I found refreshing:

> Additional space is usually referred to as **auxiliary** space complexity. With no qualifier, space complexity includes the input space requirements.
>
> My page of mine should at least reference that distinction. A better page would show some simple practical examples of how algorithms trade off time, space, and the simplicity of the algorithm, but since I haven't taught our data structures course in years, I've not returned to maintain any of those pages. Nor would I ever claim to be an expert on complexity theory. Natural language understanding, case-based reasoning, and agile software development are my strengths.
>
> I suppose it supports the claim on the top of the page about the lack of simple write ups on space complexity that this paltry page ranks as high on Google as it does.
>
> Thanks for contacting me and I hope this helps.

So it appears to be a difference in terminology rather than an outright error on anyone's part. I'm not entirely *certain* I see the usefulness of non-auxillary space complexity (including the size of the original data set) since that's a sunk cost regardless of the algorithm chosen.

In addition, I've always seen complexity as a property of the *algorithm* and, since the algorithm chosen has no control over the size of the original data set, I tend not to include it.

However, I'll be a little more specific in future, ensuring I state what I mean by space complexity in case readers aren't sure :-)

In any case, that at least clarifies why your course notes and those of North Western differ in their contentions. Regardless of which definition of space complexity you choose, one of them should be adjusted to take that into account.

Comment: What about the that sum algorithm? You don't need extra space for that one either so you're technically doing it in place as well

Comment: @committedandroider, yes you are. I believe that to be a mistake by the author.

Comment: can you clarify this? If things are passed by pointer or reference, then space is shared. If A passes a C-style array to B, there is no new space allocated.. If space is shared, then no new space will be allocated right. So passing a c style array is the same as pass by pointer?

Comment: @committedandroider: it has to do with the amount of space required. When you pass a C array, no copy is made of the array, you simply pass a pointer to the first _element_ of that array. Hence the amount of extra space needed there has nothing to do with the array size. If it were instead to make a full _copy_ of the array and pass that somehow, extra space requirements _would_ be proportional to array size.

Comment: @paxdiablo thank you so much for taking the time to explain. I want to clarify though, are you saying what you you generally refer to as space complexity is what others might call “auxiliary space complexity”?

Comment: @AjumobiOlamide: yes, you're correct - my view (one way to look at it, not the only way) is that complexity is the cost of doing something (as opposed to doing nothing). The space cost of an in-place sort does not include the original array since that is a "sunk cost". Whether you sort or not, that cost is still there.

Answer (score -1):

In essence both courses agree.

From the northwestern linked page:

> If a function A uses M units of its own space (local variables and parameters), and it calls a function B that needs N units of local space, then A overall needs M + N units of temporary workspace. What if A calls B 3 times? When a function finishes, its space can be reused, so if A calls B 3 times, it still only needs M + N units of workspace.

The focus is on function *A* and how much space it needs, but the explanation implies that *B* complexity doesn't take in account what *A* already requires. If it were the case, you could prove that any part of a programme requires as much memory as the whole programme, which would render any complexity evaluation very limited in usefulness.

Applying this to your example, the array comes from function *A* which invokes *B* (here the function `sum`), and passes it the array. `sum` does not allocate or construct the array, nor does it need to copy it, so it doesn't count in what `sum` requires.

Comment: Thank you for your input, I wish you'd provide some explanation as why you downvoted me though.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that the author from northwestern is incorrect.  The space used for a function is dependent on how much space is passed to the function, but how much space is allocated in the function during its usage.

In the sum example, the space is allocated before the function is called and it is not allocated within the function therefore it will count toward the space usage.